# How get just one value from json as string

Tags: java, json

I have following json as string:

```
{
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":"value2",
   "field3":{
      "field31":"value31",
      "field32":"value32"
   },
   "field4":{
      "field41":"value41"
   }
}
```

What is the best and the most modern way to get from this json just value from `field41`, so I would return `"value41"`. I know that I can use `JSONObject` but I'm wondering weather we have any other better option?

Comment: You could use Jackson or Gson or Jayway JSONPath, but they would do roughly the same thing as `JSONObject`, so what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

```
String json = "...";

String field41 = JsonPath.read(json, "$.field4.field41");
```

You can test it here - https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a real object out of it you can use Gson. You need to describe the class first. There are online json to Java objects converters out there. And then you can just call:

```
YourObject obj =  new Gson().fromJson(json,YourObject.class);
System.out.println(obj.getField4().getField41());
```

And there you have it!

Comment: I don't like this approach, because have to create ```YourObject``` class which may be very big and I need just one field from this class.